# How to get the main (default) text-channel with discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I want to get the text-channel that has the notification every time someone joins the server. Is there any way to do so with discord.py?
[image: The channel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Guild.system_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.system_channel) attribute, an example would be:

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    channel = ctx.guild.system_channel
    await channel.send("Whatever")
```